maximize button is not working in PHPstorm after upgrading Ubuntu 22 to 24.04
Maximize button is not working in PHPstorm after upgrading Ubuntu 22 to 24.04
In Ubuntu 24.04, unable to resize the window and click on the minimize and full screen icons.

All windows or only certain ones. This question has very little detail.

Facing display issues with multiple application. With phpstorm, button seen normal, but it didn't work, screen stuck when I click on the maximize button.
Also, one issue with Anydesk. When I open any desk, the screen area on the right size freezes. i am not even able to minimize chrome itself.
